# setcookie() does not work

Tags: php, cookies

I've tried for 2 hours now to set cookie on my page and after reading on internet a lot, I still can't find out what i'm doing wrong.
This is my code:

```
<?php

$cookie_name = "user";
$cookie_value = "MyUserName";

$days = 86400*30;
$cookie_time = $days+time();

setcookie($cookie_name, $cookie_value, $cookie_time, '/');

if (!isset($_COOKIE[$cookie_name]))
{
   echo "Cookie named '" . $cookie_name . "' is not set!";
}
else
{
echo "Cookie '" . $cookie_name . "' is set <br/>";
echo "Value is: " . $_COOKIE[$cookie_name];

?>
```

The result of my Echo is "Cookie named 'user' is not set!" every time!
Can somebody help me? :)

Comment: `setcookie()` sets a cookie and returns `false` on error. You can't assert it doesn't work if you don't verify at least two things: 1) The return value 2) Whether the HTTP header shows up in the response

Comment: BTW, your current verification is not correct. As [the manual](http://php.net/setcookie) says: "Once the cookies have been set, they can be accessed on the **next page load** with the $_COOKIE array".

Comment: Another issue you might have would be the domain you are testing on.. if it's localhost you should follow this: http://php.net/manual/ro/function.setcookie.php#73107

Comment: No, im using one.com

Answer (score 2):

your have syntax error in you code yo miss to colse the else statment

try this then your code will set the cookie

```
$cookie_name = "user";
$cookie_value = "MyUserName";

$days = 86400*30;
$cookie_time = $days+time();

setcookie($cookie_name, $cookie_value, $cookie_time, '/');

if (!isset($_COOKIE[$cookie_name]))
{
   echo "Cookie named '" . $cookie_name . "' is not set!";
}
else
{
echo "Cookie '" . $cookie_name . "' is set <br/>";
echo "Value is: " . $_COOKIE[$cookie_name];
}
```

Comment: I just forgot to close the else statment when I wrote it in here! That's not the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to close the `else` statement:

```
else
{
echo "Cookie '" . $cookie_name . "' is set <br/>";
echo "Value is: " . $_COOKIE[$cookie_name];
```

---

**Tip:** You should turn on [**Error Reporting**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) by adding this code to the top of your PHP files which will assist you in finding errors.

```
<?php 
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

Comment: I've got this when I insertet the error code: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent.

Comment: @NickiJey Can you post the full the code?